# material angular checkbox bind custom input checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using this awesome [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/0.10.1-rc4/#/), now what im trying to do is when the angular checkbox 1 is click then all the input checkbox that has a class of "column_1" will be check, same as the angular checkbox 2 and 3, clicking in any of them will then checked the corresponding input checkbox that was bind for the clicked angular checkbox e.g if click checkbox2 then all the input checkbox that has a class of "column_2" will be check, click checkbox3 then all the input checkbox that has a class of "column_3" will be check. Any help, clues, ideas, recommendation and suggestion to achieve it?

here's my html

```
<div ng-app="j_app">
  <div ng-controller="j_controller">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="check">
    </md-checkbox>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <th><md-checkbox class="checkbox1"></md-checkbox></th>
            <th><md-checkbox class="checkbox2"></md-checkbox></th>
            <th><md-checkbox class="checkbox3"></md-checkbox></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row_1">
                <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
                <td class="column_2"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
                <td class="column_3"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row_2">
                <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
                <td class="column_2"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
                <td class="column_3"><md-checkbox></md-checkbox></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my script (module and controller)

```
var app = angular.module('j_app', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('j_controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.check = {
      value1 : true,
      value2 : false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXUpBwh8yAH8L1ubR9YM?p=preview) that looks to the behavior you want :

I basically dynamically created the checkboxes to have a better control on it.

```
<th ng-repeat="(column,columnindex) in [1,2,3]">
    <md-checkbox ng-change="checkColumnCheckBoxes(columnindex,checkBoxesHeader[columnindex])" 
                 ng-model="checkBoxesHeader[columnindex]" class="checkbox1">
    </md-checkbox>
</th>

<tr class="row_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="(row,rowindex) in [1,2,3]">
    <td class="column_{{$index}}" 
        ng-repeat="(column,columnindex) in [1,2,3]">
        <md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[rowindex][columnindex] = false" 
                     ng-model="checkBoxes[rowindex][columnindex]">
        </md-checkbox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can replace "[1,2,3]" with any other counter.

My js "checkColumnCheckBoxes" function :

```
$scope.checkColumnCheckBoxes = function(index,value){
  angular.forEach($scope.checkBoxes, function(checkBox,key){
    $scope.checkBoxes[key][index] = value;
  })
}
```

I'm pretty sure you will have to rework this to your "real" needs (as you don't need a table that display only checkboxes) but it could be a solid start. If you need some help to adapt it to your needs feel free to ask.

Hope it helped.

Since your HTML is pre-generated here is how it should look like :

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <th><md-checkbox ng-change="checkColumnCheckBoxes(0,checkBoxesHeader[0])" class="checkbox1" ng-model="checkBoxesHeader[0]"></md-checkbox></th>
        <th><md-checkbox ng-change="checkColumnCheckBoxes(1,checkBoxesHeader[1])" class="checkbox2" ng-model="checkBoxesHeader[1]"></md-checkbox></th>
        <th><md-checkbox ng-change="checkColumnCheckBoxes(2,checkBoxesHeader[2])" class="checkbox3" ng-model="checkBoxesHeader[2]"></md-checkbox></th>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="row_1">
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[0][0] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[0][0]"></md-checkbox></td>
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[1][0] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[0][1]"></md-checkbox></td>
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[2][0] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[0][2]"></md-checkbox></td>
          </tr>
        <tr class="row_2">
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[0][1] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[1][0]"></md-checkbox></td>
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[1][1] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[1][1]"></md-checkbox></td>
            <td class="column_1"><md-checkbox ng-init="checkBoxes[2][1] = false" ng-model="checkBoxes[1][2]"></md-checkbox></td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

I also updated the plunker to match the exemple.

Comment: nice, but my checkboxes was created from the back-end (loop stuffs) and not through angular loop stuff. Can you show me how its done using custom stuff like not using ng-repeat? (see my reference html)

Comment: @CodeDemon you will probably have to add to you back-end some stuff that angular would have generate dynamically. I really think this is a miss-used of angular to use it in pair with a back-end generating some HTML. In my opinion angular should get the object with HTTP calls to the back-end and manage the whole view by itself. Will build you an exemple according to your needs (without ng-repeat)

Comment: thank you, anyways, i tried different approach base from your answer and seems working good so far. How can I make the md-checkbox checked by default? I can surely use ng-model and bind it with a scope (true or false) in the controller but that seems also change the other md-checkbox to checked due to having the same model. Any ideas please?

Comment: @CodeDemon In the ng-init, put the default value you want for the checkbox (instead of false)

Comment: i tried ng-init="data.cb1" and in the controller, i put $scope.data.cb1 = true; but sadly not working, any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon ng-init isn't a binding, it is an executed expression ;) ! You need to set ng-init="checkBoxes[0][0] = data.cb1" or something like that. The ng-init will just act as a line of code to execute.

Comment: @CodeDemon Did you find a solution ?

Comment: yep. I just have to add "ng-init="cb.checktrue = true" and ng-model="cb.checktrue" :)

Comment: @CodeDemon So you are now working with a list of object representing the checkboxes ?

Comment: unfortunately im new to angular (still getting to know), so far im tied up with jquery and the way im working with the material boxes is through jquery

Comment: @CodeDemon Ok :) ! Just be careful, there is a lot of unexpected behavior using jQuery within angularJS.